# How to implement a ever running loop within a PySimpleGUI code?

Tags: python, user-interface, pysimplegui

I couldnt something problem solving anywhere, so I think its time to post this question myself.

Here is my code:

```
import serial
from serial import Serial
import PySimpleGUI as sg



ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 115200, timeout=1)
read = False

sg.theme('DarkAmber')
layout = [  [sg.InputText(), sg.Button('Empfindlichkeit einstellen')],
            [sg.Button('start'), sg.Button('end')] ]

window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout)



while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if read == True:
        reading = ser.readline()
        print(reading[0:256])

    if event == "start":
        read = True

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'end':
        break

window.close()
```

The GUI shows up just perfectly fine and there are no errors. But the problem is the following part:

```
    if read == True:
        reading = ser.readline()
        print(reading[0:256])
```

This part of the code should run continuously when I pressed the button that says "start" once. But it doesnt. This part of the code just get executed one time, whenever I have pressed start once and then any other button. How can I fix this?

Comment: The call to `readline()` will block until a newline is received. You need to make the operation non-blocking, or move it to a dedicated, non-GUI thread in which blocking is acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
event, values = window.read()
```

It will stop here to wait event happen. After button 'start' clicked first time,

```py
if event == "start":
    read = True
```

Variable `read` set to `True` after that event, then back to `window.read()` again to wait another event. There's no more event, so wait there.

To avoid to wait event there, you can use option `timeout` in method `window.read()` for how long to wait.

```py
event, values = window.read(timeout=100)    # 100 ms to wait
```

Option `timeout`, milliseconds to wait until the Read will return if no other GUI events happen first. Default event or key is `__TIMEOUT__`.

Comment: This is the way.